# Evernote Paste without formatting doesn't work

Tags: evernote

When I copy text with link at chrome browser and Paste without formatting(ctrl+Shift+V), it is pasted with link and bold style. Before I change my laptop to new one, it is pasted only text with no style applied and hyperlink removed.
Also, "Ctrl+Space" with selected text doesn't remove link. Neither do "Ctrl+Shift+Space" work.
Simply, I cannot remove style and link from text in evernote at all.
This is very annoying.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: When I've encountered problems with other applications where I've had similar issues, I first paste whatever I want to put in the application as plain text into Notepad, if it is a Microsoft Windows system, or some other text editor first, then highlight and copy the same information in the text editor, then paste it into the application.

Comment: @moonpoint Yeah, That's a one solution. But, it's little bit harder than directly paste to evernote. I have to paste many times for make one note. So, paste to Notepad first method is a second-best solution maybe.

Comment: I agree; I'd prefer to just paste the data into the application as text with a shortcut key combination or even selecting a "paste special" menu entry in the application that would allow me to paste the text without any formatting applied, but with some applications that has been the only solution available to me.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, this is really the biggest problem with Evernote. There is so much formatting that you can never get rid of.

But I just found this Windows utility, and it seems to work well at filtering the clipboard contents to be only text.

If you use the Evernote web clipper in your browser to create the note, you will still have to Select All in the note, then Copy, but then you can Win-V to paste back into the note as text only.

http://stevemiller.net/puretext/